# Sending a message on a guildMemberAdd event in the server on Discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i'm coding a discord bot with JavaScript. It's running pretty good, but the only thing i can't do is sending a message in the server when a new member joins the server. (Not a private message, directly a message in the server). I don't find any way to do that, any ideas ?

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', function(member){
  member.send("Hello there !");
});
```

This one sends a private message, it does exactly what i don't want it to do ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `member` parameter that gets passed into the callback function is exactly that--an object representing a discord member. If you want to send a message to the *guild* the member just joined, you will need to get the guild property of the member, `member.guild` and then `get` the channel you want from `channels` and `send` the message you wish. All together it should look something like this:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', function(member){
  member.guild.channels.get("put-channel-id-here").send("Hello there!")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may know by now but in Discord.js v12 (current stable version), you would use

```js
member.guild.channels.cache.get("put-channel-id here").send("Hello there!")
```